# How to store field from a database after changing scenes in JavaFX? Need to capture an "ID" from database table after login

Tags: java, sql, javafx, h2

I am creating a JavaFX application similar to Uber and other ride sharing applications. A user can sign up as either a "Rider" or a "Driver". Then, they can login and so far, the application will load one of two scenes, depending on if they are a "Rider" or a "Driver". I want to display their information on their profile, but am having trouble capturing the user's information after changing from the `Login` scene to the `Rider`/`Driver` scenes. Also, JavaFX is new to me, so my "working" code might not be optimal.

In my `LoginController` file, the user is logged in with this method after their information has been authenticated:

```
private void loginUser(ActionEvent actionEvent, String scenePath) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Login Successful!"); //Testing purposes
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(scenePath));
    Scene userScene = new Scene(root);

    setScene(actionEvent, userScene);
}
```

Then, they are redirected to the correct scene, as a "Rider" or a "Driver".

I am currently working on the `RiderController` class that will handle the back-end of the `Rider.fxml`.

`RiderController` has the following `intialize()` method to automatically retrieve database information

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    try {
        userName.setText(databaseManager.selectUser());
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And finally, here is the `selectUser()` method that queries the database. For now, I have hard coded an ID to make sure the method actually prints a `FIRST_NAME` from the database (it does).

```
public String selectUser() throws SQLException {
    String sql = "SELECT FIRST_NAME FROM USER WHERE ID = ?";
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    preparedStatement.setInt(1, 1);

    String userName = "default";
    ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next()) {
        userName = rs.getString("FIRST_NAME");
    }
    return userName;
}
```

I am expecting to be able to somehow pass the ID from the database row with the user that was able to login, after the login page.

Comment: This will be frowned upon by some users here but we use a static variable like this declaration static String firstTIME = "TRUE"; If you use it on another stage scene it need to be imported and this type of variable hold the information until it is changed or set to noting firstTIME - " ";

Comment: The issue is quite complex.  It is not clear what your login procedure is.  It should return a DTO containing the user's data.  This DTO is submitted to the controllers.  Depending on when you submit it (and how you create the controllers), you may also need to change their initialization process.

Comment: @Suede If this suggestion does not work let us know and we will post code. First we suggest you have a Main Screen that has two buttons that say Login or Sign Up as Driver and one that says the same thing for the Rider after the selection the user creates info in the database like User Name and Password after that all navigation going back or logging out takes the user back to the Main Screen If this design is not workable please explain why or post some code that shows how the DB tables are created and the complete code for your login screen

Comment: Grendel, that is exactly how it already currently works. The sign up button then takes to a registration scene that will insert information into the DB tables. I originally set this up with a public static variable, but found another way to pass state and will updated this question with the solution later.